# Ipsec config with openswan

Tags: vpn, ipsec, openswan

I try to configure Ipsec  on server with openswan  as client.
But receive error  - possible, it's  auth error.

What I wrote wrong in config ?

Thank you for answers.

---

```
 #1: STATE_MAIN_I2: sent MI2, expecting MR2    
003 "f-net" #1: received Vendor ID payload [Cisco-Unity]    
003 "f-net" #1: received Vendor ID payload [Dead Peer Detection]    
003 "f-net" #1: ignoring unknown Vendor ID payload     [ca917959574c7d5aed4222a9df367018]    
003 "f-net" #1: received Vendor ID payload [XAUTH]    
108 "f-net" #1: STATE_MAIN_I3: sent MI3, expecting MR3    
003 "f-net" #1: discarding duplicate packet; already STATE_MAIN_I3    
010 "f-net" #1: STATE_MAIN_I3: retransmission; will wait 20s for response    
003 "f-net" #1: discarding duplicate packet; already STATE_MAIN_I3    
003 "f-net" #1: discarding duplicate packet; already STATE_MAIN_I3    
003 "f-net" #1: discarding duplicate packet; already STATE_MAIN_I3    
010 "f-net" #1: STATE_MAIN_I3: retransmission; will wait 40s for response    
031 "f-net" #1: max number of retransmissions (2) reached STATE_MAIN_I3.      Possible authentication failure: no acceptable response to our first encrypted message    
000 "f-net" #1: starting keying attempt 2 of at most 3, but releasing whack
```

---

### other side - Cisco ASA.

```
parameters for my connection  on our Linux server :    

 VPN Gateway   8.*.*.*    (Cisco )
Phase 1    
Exchange Type    
Main Mode    
Identification Type    
IP Address    
Local ID           4.*.*.*     (our Linux server IP)    
Remote ID          8.*.*.*     (VPN server IP)    
Authentication        PSK    
Pre Shared Key           
Diffie-Hellman Key Group DH 5 (1536 bit) or DH 2 (1024 bit)    
Encryption Algorithm   AES 256    
HMAC Function          SHA-1
Lifetime          86.400 seconds / no volume limit
Phase 2
Security Protocol     ESP
Connection Mode       Tunnel
Encryption Algorithm  AES 256
HMAC Function         SHA-1
Lifetime              3600 seconds / 4.608.000 kilobytes
DPD / IKE Keepalive   15 seconds
PFS                off
Remote Network        192.168.100.0/24
Local Network 1       10.0.0.0/16
...............
Local Network 5
```

---

```
current openswan config :

#
config setup
klipsdebug=all
plutodebug="control parsing"
protostack=netkey
nat_traversal=no
virtual_private=%v4:10.0.0.0/8,%v4:192.168.0.0/16,%v4:172.16.0.0/12
oe=off    
nhelpers=0    


conn f-net

type=tunnel
keyexchange=ike
authby=secret
auth=esp
esp=aes256-sha1
keyingtries=3
pfs=no
aggrmode=no

keylife=3600s
ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024
#    
left=4.*.*.*
leftsubnet=10.0.0.0/16
leftid=4.*.*.*
leftnexthop=%defaultroute  
right=8.*.*.*
rightsubnet=192.168.100.0/24
rightid=8.*.*.*
rightnexthop=%defaultroute 
auto=add
```

Answer (score 1):

problem was in ESXi bridge.  (Virt server on our side located on ESXI host with external IP)
on same system, but worked on nake hardware  (same SL6-RHEL6), ipsec works fine.

```
config on our side : 


conn f-net    
type=tunnel    
keyexchange=ike    
authby=secret    
auth=esp    
esp=aes-sha1    
keyingtries=3    
pfs=no    
ike=aes256-sha1-modp1536    ##   also works  without it    
left=4***    
leftsubnet=****    
leftid=4***    
leftnexthop=%defaultroute      # correct in many situations    
right=8***           # Remote vitals    
rightsubnet=****    
rightid=8***    
rightnexthop=%defaultroute     # correct in many situations    
auto=add
```